# Is a is_variadic type trait possible in C++17?

Tags: variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++17, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Is it possible, in `C++17`, to design a type trait which would detect whether a callable is variadic (and therefore can take an arbitrarily long number of parameters) or not?

```
template <class Callable>
struct is_variadic;
```

I currently do not see how to do that, but I cannot convince myself that it's not doable. So if it's doable what would that look like?

Comment: Why would you ever need to ask this question of a type?

Comment: A couple of questions about your question. (1) With "an arbitrarily number of parameters" do you mean an arbitrary number of parameter of the same type or of arbitrary types? (2) Can be acceptable a solution that detect if a callable is callable with a number of parameter to a fixed limit (by example, to a max of 100 parameter)?